# Regular Expression remove specific text in file name

Tags: regex, pdf

I am using a file transferring tool that allows the use of Regular Expression to rename files as they are copied into a new folder (so I am working with Regular Expression only and not inside a code base) I have a large set of files with a specific naming convention with a version number at the end of the file name. My goal is to remove this file version number along with the underscore.

Here are some examples of the file names:

- `the_file_name_DS_017_EN_35.pdf`
- `the_file_name_DS_037_SP_35.pdf`
- `different_filename_DS_EN_5.pdf`

I am looking to change them to:

- `the_file_name_DS_017_EN.pdf`
- `the_file_name_DS_037_SP.pdf`
- `different_filename_DS_EN.pdf`

I am trying to remove the version number so that the file naming convention on my new server will always be the same. I am not good with regex and this is what I tried so far but to no avail:

Using `_[^_]+$` it selects last underscore along with the `.pdf` extension.

Using `\_(.*?)\.` it selects the first underscore until the period.

How do I select the last underscore until the period removing that text but keeping the period? Maybe there is a better method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: TBH I am not sure. I am using a tool called limagito and it has a [help page](http://limagito.com/helpx/Help.htm?Renaming.html) but doesnt mention anything specific that i could see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you regex motor works with positive lookaheads, you might work it like this and replace it by nothing

```
(_\d+)(?=\.pdf$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bDxBgU/2)**

Explanation :

- `(_\d+)` will follow an underscore following by one or more digits
- `(?=\.pdf$)` will match as a positive lookahead the `.pdf` extension at the end of the file name

Comment: Boom! This is it! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

TRY to use the regular expression here:

> _[0-9]*\.

and replace it by

> .

Comment: I checked your answer and it ends up selecting different sections of the string that have underscores in them. Thanks for responding tho

Comment: i think u missed the \ before the .
Initially when I typed this the editor removed it. So had to correct it by adding a back slash before the 2nd. @crazymatt

Comment: Ahh yes you are correct. I may have tested it before you had fixed it. Thanks for the alternative solution.